# Windows 10 does not recognise second external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, drive-letter

After a RAID drive failure I am left with two identical 500GB SSD 2.5" drives which appear to be in good working order (fortunately I've recovered my data from the RAID drives). I have bought two identical USB enclosures for them and I wish to use them both as separate backup drives.

My problem is that Windows 10 doesn't seem to be able to tell the difference between the two drives. It seems to think they are one and the same thing.

I shall explain.  Let's call them Drive 1 and Drive 2. I can plug in Drive 1 and windows recognizes it. I can then plug in Drive 2 and I can hear the distinctive chime as Windows notices a USB device has been plugged in, but it doesn't show in This PC.

Exactly the same thing happens if I plug in Drive 2 first. Windows recognises it, but upon plugging in Drive 1 it too is not seen.

I have tried changing the letter allocation of Drive 1 to Z:. Now, if I unplug Drive 1 and plug in Drive 2 it thinks that drive is also Z:, despite me not allocating a new letter to Drive 2. Every combination of plugging in, unplugging, allocating drive letters, etc. seems to make no difference - Windows 10 seems to regard them as the same device.

The difference is, I have named one "SSD Backup 1" and the other "SSD Backup 2" and Windows honours this difference so I can tell which physical drive Windows is currently viewing.

In Device Manager I can see that two USB drives are recognized - i.e. I can see my laptop's internal HD, and the two external USB drives. Also, when I go to eject the USB drives it shows that two drives are connected, although only one of them is named.

Comment: "It seems to think they are one and the same thing." - I can only assume you are using RAID 1 (Mirror).  What you describe is expected. What file system was on this RAID?

Comment: No - I have removed them from the RAID enclosure and have reformatted them (quick format). They are now, as far as I understand, completely separate drives in separate enclosures, into separate USB ports.

Comment: So you deleted the partitions on the disk, did you recreate a partition, on the disk? When you use a S.M.A.R.T disk utility, do both disks, identify themselves uniquely?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of 'Disk Management' (WIN+R then type `diskmgmt.msc`) with the two USB drives connected. Make sure it is expanded to show all of the system's drives.

Comment: Open disc management, check that windows see the two drives as two different drives, this is not dependent on drive letters etc (careful in here, you can do damage). The I would completely repartition the drives (and reformat) just in case. That should wipe any raid related stuff from them. Hopefully fixing the issue for you.

Comment: The drives we seemingly corrupted. I managed to recover my data, and then all I did was a quick format to get them up and running again. I don't know about SMART disk utility - will it help if I learn a little about it and run a test?

Comment: Smart is only likely helpful for giving you drive health data.  But it might tell you if the drives are starting to fail. How did you check the drives are healthy?

Comment: @Netspud2K, Disk Management does not recognise both drives when they are plugged in. It only recognises the first that is plugged in, be that Drive 1 or Drive 2. They they both appear using the same drive letter.

Comment: OK, I would plug them in 1 at a time. Completely remove the partitions, and repartition and format. See if that helps.

Comment: I should have asked, do you have a software or hardware RAID?

Comment: "Did I have"... past tense :) TBH, I'm not entirely sure - this isn't my specialism. I assume it was hardware... it was an enclosure that housed the two drives, with dip switches to change the raid type.

Comment: Currently doing a full reformat of first drive... hoping it'll help.

Comment: Hi Doug, yes, that would be considered hardware, because it is not a software raid on the PC.  Repartitioning was the important part. You need to wipe any potential for the two drives to be linked with each other.  I am not 100% sure what the issue is, but if you did a quick format, there must be something at the partition level, which is as low as you could go to clear a drive.

Comment: Sorted! Thanks @Netspud2K

Comment: Fab, glad you got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @Netspud2K I got this problem sorted. I shifted my data onto my internal hard drive, and did a full reformat of both SSDs.

After this I noticed that, when hovering over the drives in Disk Management, both drives were shown but there was a message: "The disk is offline because it has a signature collision with another disk that is online".

Right click > "online" on the offending drive fixed this issue. Now both drives can be seen and used independently when plugged in.